# Using JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi I'm small a little issue trying to append some text to a `JTextArea` from another class within the same  package. Below is the main class that pertains to the JFrame:

```
  public class Client extends JFrame{

        //Static variables
        private static final String host = "localhost";
        private static final int portNumber = 4444;

        //Variables
        private String userName;

        //JFrame Variables
        private JPanel contentPanel;
        private JTabbedPane panel_Social;
        private JPanel jpanel_Social;
        private JPanel jpanel_Chat;
        private JTextArea textArea_Receive;
        private JTextField textField_Send;
        private JTextArea textArea_ClientList;
        private JButton btn_Enter;


        public JTextArea getTextArea_Receive(){
            return this.textArea_Receive;
        }

        //Constructor
        private Client(String userName, String host, int portNumber){
            this.userName = userName;
            this.serverHost = host;
            this.serverPort = portNumber;
        }

        public void main(String args[]){
            //Requests user to enter name
            String readName = null;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter username");
            readName = scan.nextLine();

            //Start client
            Client client = new Client(readName, host, portNumber);
            client.startClient(scan);
        }

        private void startClient(Scanner scan){
            try{
                //Create new socket and wait for network communication
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                //Create thread and start it
                serverThread = new ServerThread(socket, userName);
                Thread serverAccessThread = new Thread(serverThread);
                serverAccessThread.start();
            }
        }
    }


Below is the serverThread class

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable{

        private Socket socket;
        private String userName;
        private boolean isAlived;
        private final LinkedList<String> messagesToSend;
        private boolean hasMessages = false;

        //Constructor
        ServerThread(Socket socket,  String userName){
            this.socket = socket;
            this.userName = userName;
            messagesToSend = new LinkedList<String>();
        }

        public void run(){   
            try{
                Client test1 = new Client();
                JTextArea test2 = test1.getTextArea_Receive();
                String test3 = "Hello World";
                test2.append(test3);
            } catch (IOException e){
}
    }
```

I included test variables just to easily recreate the issue but whenever the append function is run nothing appears in the text area of the jFrame. In my scenario I'm having the client receive text from a server then append it to the text box.

BTW I'm using the IntelliJ GUI designer for the JFrame. I've only included code needed to recreate the problem. I'm still trying to create MCVE questions so feel free to let me know mistakes I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `Client` into `ServerThread` via the constructor. The `Client` you are instantiating within `run()` is not the same reference to the `Client` you created in `main()`. So your `ServerThread` class would be something like

```
ServerThread(Client client, Socket socket,  String userName) {
    this.client = client;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.userName = userName;
    messagesToSend = new LinkedList<String>();
}

public void run() {
    try
    {
        JTextArea test2 = this.client.getTextArea_Receive();
        String test3 = "Hello World";
        test2.append(test3);
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
}
```

Your `startClient()` method would be updated to something like this

```
private void startClient(Client client, Scanner scan)
{
    try
    {
        //Create new socket and wait for network communication
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //Create thread and start it
        ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(client, socket, userName);
        serverAccessThread.run();
    }
}
```

---

All that being said,

I would recommend moving your `main()` out of `Client` and into a class that isn't so coupled to the Swing UI code. Something like this:

```
public class MySwingApplication {

    private static final String host = "localhost";
    private static final int portNumber = 4444;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Requests user to enter name
        // Start client
    }
}
```

Your `Client` is then built more like an instance object

```
public class Client extends JFrame {
    public JTextArea getTextArea_Receive(){
        // Return the text area
    }

    // Constructor -- public to allow instantiation from main()
    public Client(String userName, String host, int portNumber) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    private void startClient(Scanner scan) {
        // Show the JFrame on screen
        // Spawn Server
    }
}
```

Comment: This works greeat. I can see in the debugger that all the information matches up but the TextArea still isn't showing the text I'm sending to it. Also why do you suggest moving my main out of the client? @j.seashell

Comment: I'm not sure why your text isn't updating. There may be some sort of refresh/re-render that you need to look into, sorry I can't be more helpful there. But regarding ```main()```...your ```Client``` object is something that doesn't really need to be holding state (```static```). Really, you'd have a class that is in no way coupled to your Swing UI, that contains your ```main()```. Then you'd launch the client from that ```main()``` method. I'll update my answer with a separate section with what I'm describing

Comment: Can we also recognise that both the op’s and your solution is violating the single thread rules of Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah definitely. I just didn't want to get into all that. The answer was getting very long.

Comment: @Lucky38i *"but the TextArea still isn't showing the text I'm sending to it"* - Are you sure the client is receiving the text?

Comment: @j.seashell Perfect practice makes perfect - while this addresses the "immediate" issue, it fails to cover all the issues the code/approach the OP is making, which means we are likely to see yet another question, presenting your code and I don't want to be the one who has to tell the OP that the person who answered their last question didn't do so adequately :/ - there is enough bad examples on the net

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it works fine through CLI but not through the jframe. Can you explain the bad practices I'm making with Swing as well?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Go ahead and submit a more fundamentally helpful answer. I know mine isn't all the way there but I'm not going to rewrite OP's application in an SO answer. OP, you should accept MadProgrammer's answer once it is posted.

Answer (score 1):

> the append function is run nothing appears in the text area of the jFrame

There's not enough information available in you question to ascertain why this might be happening, how ever, there are a number of important pieces of information you need to take into account.

1. Swing is single threaded and not thread safe
2. You want to, as much as possible, decouple of the code

Basically, the first point means that you shouldn't be running any long running or blocking processes within the Event Dispatching Thread AND you should not be modifying the UI (or any state the UI relies on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

The second point means that, for even given part of your code, you want to be asking, "how hard would it be to replace it with some other implementation?" - If the amount of work scares you, then your code is probably to tightly coupled.

To that end, I started with...

```
public interface Client {
    public void append(String message);
}
```

This is really basic, but it means that some component can send a message to some other component and neither should care about each other beyond this capability.

Next, I looked at `ServerThread`. Basically this class becomes responsible for the management of the `Socket` and delivery of the messages to the `Client`.  Because of the requirements of Swing, I've used a `SwingWorker`.  This allows me to run the `Socket` code on a background thread, but ensure that the messages are delivered to the `Client` within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class ServerThread extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private Client client;

    //Constructor
    ServerThread(String host, int port, Client client) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String message : chunks) {
            client.append(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port)) {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                String text = null;
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(text);
                    if (text.equals("<stop>")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    publish(text);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            publish("Failed to establish connection to " + host + ":" + port + " - " + exp.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then the actual UI client itself...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    //Constructor
    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    ClientUI clientUI = new ClientUI();

                    ServerThread thread = new ServerThread("localhost", 4321, clientUI);
                    thread.execute();

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");
                    frame.add(clientUI);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClientUI extends JPanel implements Client {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public ClientUI() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        }

        @Override
        public void append(String message) {
            ta.append(message + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Not much going on here

Finally, I wrote a simple `Server` test the code, which simply sends the current date/time as a `String` to the connected client.

When I say simple, I mean simple.  This is intended, by design, to tell with a single client connection and is meant only for testing the above code

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG);
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4321)) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Write >> ");
                    writer.write(format.format(new Date()));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.flush();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To test it all, start the `Server` and then run the `Main` class

Comment: I don't need to configure the UI as this is done through the UI designer and all the settings in a .form file. Also my server class is multi-threaded to accept multiple clients. So I'm fine there. I don't understand the process function in serverThread and what it's doing. Also in the doInBackground I'm confused as to what publish(text) IS. Thanks for the explanation though it's helping me understand a lot

Comment: Then you should read through the linked documentation - including [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: this is working. I  have a statement that changed to true in the main file once a scanner sees that I've made an input. Upon being true in the ServerThread I have it so that it writes the input I made to the server. However, it's no carrying out these instructions.